# A simple form submission but notice : Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: page-template, forms, fatal-error

after 3 hours... I give up and I request the wordpress developers community.

I have to create a contest on a site based on Wordpress. There are 3 steps :

1. user enters his information
2. if all the inputs are valid, I redirect to the game page
3. The user plays and then he is redirected to the results page.

I created a page "Step 1", "Step 2"... and I associated a template for each page.

All the logic is in the templates. I just started the validation of fields, I had this error that I don't understand.

```
Error : Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/web/www.mysite.com/_online/wp-includes/post-template.php on line 29
```

Template :

```
/*
Template Name: QUIZ - Step 1
*/

get_header();

if ( isset($_POST['participe'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['gender'])
        && isset($_POST['lastname']) && !empty($_POST['lastname'])
        && isset($_POST['firstname']) && !empty($_POST['firstname'])
        && isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email'])
        && isset($_POST['day']) && !empty($_POST['day'])
        && isset($_POST['month']) && !empty($_POST['month'])
        && isset($_POST['year']) && !empty($_POST['year'])
        && isset($_POST['status'])
            && isset($_POST['place'])
        && isset($_POST['newsletter'])
        )
    {
        echo 'ok';  
    }
    else {
        echo 'ko';
    }
}
```

When I let all the fields empty, I have the echo "ko" but when I fill all of them I have the previous error...

Comment: Can we have more code please?  It's impossible to answer to that with few details you provided.

Comment: WordPress uses `day`, `month`, and `year`, you should always prefix generic vars with something unique to prevent collisions.

Comment: The error is at line 29. Where is line 29? There are not even 29 lines in the code you provided.